# Rails+Heroku | Missing subpage from routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to load my subpage but I get the message

`"The page you were looking for does not exist. You may have mistyped the address or the page may have moved.`

In routes, I have mapped addresses for all subpages
You may have mistyped the address or the page may have moved. ". I do not know why but this error occurred when I added the index action to before_action "set_job" in the "jobs" controller.

**Heroku logs:**

```
2018-06-17T15:43:19.406782+00:00 app[web.1]: [0a3d4fad-180e-45bd-86fa-2fb07e922f2e] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:25:in `call'
2018-06-17T15:43:19.406783+00:00 app[web.1]: [0a3d4fad-180e-45bd-86fa-2fb07e922f2e] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
2018-06-17T15:43:19.406785+00:00 app[web.1]: [0a3d4fad-180e-45bd-86fa-2fb07e922f2e] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
2018-06-17T15:43:19.406787+00:00 app[web.1]: [0a3d4fad-180e-45bd-86fa-2fb07e922f2e] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:27:in `call'
2018-06-17T15:43:19.406788+00:00 app[web.1]: [0a3d4fad-180e-45bd-86fa-2fb07e922f2e] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
2018-06-17T15:43:19.406790+00:00 app[web.1]: [0a3d4fad-180e-45bd-86fa-2fb07e922f2e] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:125:in `call'
2018-06-17T15:43:19.406791+00:00 app[web.1]: [0a3d4fad-180e-45bd-86fa-2fb07e922f2e] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
2018-06-17T15:43:19.406793+00:00 app[web.1]: [0a3d4fad-180e-45bd-86fa-2fb07e922f2e] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
2018-06-17T15:43:19.406794+00:00 app[web.1]: [0a3d4fad-180e-45bd-86fa-2fb07e922f2e] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/puma-3.11.4/lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in `call'
2018-06-17T15:43:19.406796+00:00 app[web.1]: [0a3d4fad-180e-45bd-86fa-2fb07e922f2e] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/puma-3.11.4/lib/puma/server.rb:632:in `handle_request'
2018-06-17T15:43:19.406798+00:00 app[web.1]: [0a3d4fad-180e-45bd-86fa-2fb07e922f2e] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/puma-3.11.4/lib/puma/server.rb:446:in `process_client'
2018-06-17T15:43:19.406799+00:00 app[web.1]: [0a3d4fad-180e-45bd-86fa-2fb07e922f2e] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/puma-3.11.4/lib/puma/server.rb:306:in `block in run'
2018-06-17T15:43:19.406801+00:00 app[web.1]: [0a3d4fad-180e-45bd-86fa-2fb07e922f2e] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/puma-3.11.4/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `block in spawn_thread'
2018-06-17T15:43:19.425933+00:00 app[web.1]: [edbaed7b-ff1e-4a30-940c-8c6dbc4a35af] Started GET "/uploads/post/image/1/las.jpg" for 176.115.15.103 at 2018-06-17 15:43:19 +0000
2018-06-17T15:43:19.426945+00:00 app[web.1]: [edbaed7b-ff1e-4a30-940c-8c6dbc4a35af]
2018-06-17T15:43:19.427003+00:00 app[web.1]: [edbaed7b-ff1e-4a30-940c-8c6dbc4a35af] ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/uploads/post/image/1/las.jpg"):
2018-06-17T15:43:19.427031+00:00 app[web.1]: [edbaed7b-ff1e-4a30-940c-8c6dbc4a35af]
2018-06-17T15:43:19.427089+00:00 app[web.1]: [edbaed7b-ff1e-4a30-940c-8c6dbc4a35af] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:63:in `call'
2018-06-17T15:43:19.427090+00:00 app[web.1]: [edbaed7b-ff1e-4a30-940c-8c6dbc4a35af] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
2018-06-17T15:43:19.427091+00:00 app[web.1]: [edbaed7b-ff1e-4a30-940c-8c6dbc4a35af] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
2018-06-17T15:43:19.427093+00:00 app[web.1]: [edbaed7b-ff1e-4a30-940c-8c6dbc4a35af] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
2018-06-17T15:43:19.427094+00:00 app[web.1]: [edbaed7b-ff1e-4a30-940c-8c6dbc4a35af] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `block in tagged'
2018-06-17T15:43:19.427095+00:00 app[web.1]: [edbaed7b-ff1e-4a30-940c-8c6dbc4a35af] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
2018-06-17T15:43:19.427097+00:00 app[web.1]: [edbaed7b-ff1e-4a30-940c-8c6dbc4a35af] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `tagged'
2018-06-17T15:43:19.427098+00:00 app[web.1]: [edbaed7b-ff1e-4a30-940c-8c6dbc4a35af] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
2018-06-17T15:43:19.427099+00:00 app[web.1]: [edbaed7b-ff1e-4a30-940c-8c6dbc4a35af] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in `call'
2018-06-17T15:43:19.427103+00:00 app[web.1]: [edbaed7b-ff1e-4a30-940c-8c6dbc4a35af] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
2018-06-17T15:43:19.427104+00:00 app[web.1]: [edbaed7b-ff1e-4a30-940c-8c6dbc4a35af] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:27:in `call'
2018-06-17T15:43:19.427105+00:00 app[web.1]: [edbaed7b-ff1e-4a30-940c-8c6dbc4a35af] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
2018-06-17T15:43:19.427100+00:00 app[web.1]: [edbaed7b-ff1e-4a30-940c-8c6dbc4a35af] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:25:in `call'
2018-06-17T15:43:19.427101+00:00 app[web.1]: [edbaed7b-ff1e-4a30-940c-8c6dbc4a35af] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
2018-06-17T15:43:19.427108+00:00 app[web.1]: [edbaed7b-ff1e-4a30-940c-8c6dbc4a35af] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
2018-06-17T15:43:19.427109+00:00 app[web.1]: [edbaed7b-ff1e-4a30-940c-8c6dbc4a35af] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
2018-06-17T15:43:19.427110+00:00 app[web.1]: [edbaed7b-ff1e-4a30-940c-8c6dbc4a35af] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/puma-3.11.4/lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in `call'
2018-06-17T15:43:19.427107+00:00 app[web.1]: [edbaed7b-ff1e-4a30-940c-8c6dbc4a35af] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:125:in `call'
2018-06-17T15:43:19.427112+00:00 app[web.1]: [edbaed7b-ff1e-4a30-940c-8c6dbc4a35af] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/puma-3.11.4/lib/puma/server.rb:446:in `process_client'
2018-06-17T15:43:19.427111+00:00 app[web.1]: [edbaed7b-ff1e-4a30-940c-8c6dbc4a35af] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/puma-3.11.4/lib/puma/server.rb:632:in `handle_request'
2018-06-17T15:43:19.427113+00:00 app[web.1]: [edbaed7b-ff1e-4a30-940c-8c6dbc4a35af] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/puma-3.11.4/lib/puma/server.rb:306:in `block in run'
2018-06-17T15:43:19.427114+00:00 app[web.1]: [edbaed7b-ff1e-4a30-940c-8c6dbc4a35af] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/puma-3.11.4/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `block in spawn_thread'
2018-06-17T15:43:19.208024+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=stark-fortress-73015.herokuapp.com request_id=3e0775b5-3abc-462e-8249-25e2d5bfca5c fwd="176.115.15.103" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=20ms status=200 bytes=8537 protocol=https
2018-06-17T15:43:19.407161+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/css/landing.css" host=stark-fortress-73015.herokuapp.com request_id=0a3d4fad-180e-45bd-86fa-2fb07e922f2e fwd="176.115.15.103" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=404 bytes=1902 protocol=https
2018-06-17T15:43:19.429723+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/uploads/post/image/1/las.jpg" host=stark-fortress-73015.herokuapp.com request_id=edbaed7b-ff1e-4a30-940c-8c6dbc4a35af fwd="176.115.15.103" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=404 bytes=1902 protocol=https
2018-06-17T15:43:20.018057+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=stark-fortress-73015.herokuapp.com request_id=6d908b07-9fd1-4b47-a4aa-c463aa42cc57 fwd="176.115.15.103" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2ms status=200 bytes=143 protocol=https
2018-06-17T15:43:28.283085+00:00 app[web.1]: [100078cd-e2ed-4e6c-a0c9-9431a5073b8a] Started GET "/jobs" for 176.115.15.103 at 2018-06-17 15:43:28 +0000
2018-06-17T15:43:28.287288+00:00 app[web.1]: [100078cd-e2ed-4e6c-a0c9-9431a5073b8a]   Job Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  "jobs".* FROM "jobs" WHERE "jobs"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", nil], ["LIMIT", 1]]
2018-06-17T15:43:28.284027+00:00 app[web.1]: [100078cd-e2ed-4e6c-a0c9-9431a5073b8a] Processing by JobsController#index as HTML
2018-06-17T15:43:28.287843+00:00 app[web.1]: [100078cd-e2ed-4e6c-a0c9-9431a5073b8a] Completed 404 Not Found in 4ms (ActiveRecord: 1.1ms)
2018-06-17T15:43:28.288355+00:00 app[web.1]: [100078cd-e2ed-4e6c-a0c9-9431a5073b8a]
2018-06-17T15:43:28.288387+00:00 app[web.1]: [100078cd-e2ed-4e6c-a0c9-9431a5073b8a] ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Job with 'id'=):
2018-06-17T15:43:28.288423+00:00 app[web.1]: [100078cd-e2ed-4e6c-a0c9-9431a5073b8a]
2018-06-17T15:43:28.288489+00:00 app[web.1]: [100078cd-e2ed-4e6c-a0c9-9431a5073b8a] app/controllers/jobs_controller.rb:6:in `set_job'
2018-06-17T15:43:28.469544+00:00 app[web.1]: [ab5da2ad-516f-4b5f-864f-a9040c901875] Started GET "/uploads/post/image/1/las.jpg" for 176.115.15.103 at 2018-06-17 15:43:28 +0000
2018-06-17T15:43:28.470205+00:00 app[web.1]: [ab5da2ad-516f-4b5f-864f-a9040c901875]
2018-06-17T15:43:28.470237+00:00 app[web.1]: [ab5da2ad-516f-4b5f-864f-a9040c901875] ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/uploads/post/image/1/las.jpg"):
2018-06-17T15:43:28.470272+00:00 app[web.1]: [ab5da2ad-516f-4b5f-864f-a9040c901875]
2018-06-17T15:43:28.470316+00:00 app[web.1]: [ab5da2ad-516f-4b5f-864f-a9040c901875] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:63:in `call'
2018-06-17T15:43:28.470318+00:00 app[web.1]: [ab5da2ad-516f-4b5f-864f-a9040c901875] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
2018-06-17T15:43:28.470320+00:00 app[web.1]: [ab5da2ad-516f-4b5f-864f-a9040c901875] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
2018-06-17T15:43:28.470322+00:00 app[web.1]: [ab5da2ad-516f-4b5f-864f-a9040c901875] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
2018-06-17T15:43:28.470324+00:00 app[web.1]: [ab5da2ad-516f-4b5f-864f-a9040c901875] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `block in tagged'
2018-06-17T15:43:28.470326+00:00 app[web.1]: [ab5da2ad-516f-4b5f-864f-a9040c901875] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
2018-06-17T15:43:28.470327+00:00 app[web.1]: [ab5da2ad-516f-4b5f-864f-a9040c901875] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `tagged'
2018-06-17T15:43:28.470329+00:00 app[web.1]: [ab5da2ad-516f-4b5f-864f-a9040c901875] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
2018-06-17T15:43:28.470331+00:00 app[web.1]: [ab5da2ad-516f-4b5f-864f-a9040c901875] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in `call'
2018-06-17T15:43:28.470332+00:00 app[web.1]: [ab5da2ad-516f-4b5f-864f-a9040c901875] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:25:in `call'
2018-06-17T15:43:28.470334+00:00 app[web.1]: [ab5da2ad-516f-4b5f-864f-a9040c901875] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
2018-06-17T15:43:28.470336+00:00 app[web.1]: [ab5da2ad-516f-4b5f-864f-a9040c901875] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
2018-06-17T15:43:28.470338+00:00 app[web.1]: [ab5da2ad-516f-4b5f-864f-a9040c901875] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:27:in `call'
2018-06-17T15:43:28.470340+00:00 app[web.1]: [ab5da2ad-516f-4b5f-864f-a9040c901875] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
2018-06-17T15:43:28.470341+00:00 app[web.1]: [ab5da2ad-516f-4b5f-864f-a9040c901875] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:125:in `call'
2018-06-17T15:43:28.470343+00:00 app[web.1]: [ab5da2ad-516f-4b5f-864f-a9040c901875] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
2018-06-17T15:43:28.470345+00:00 app[web.1]: [ab5da2ad-516f-4b5f-864f-a9040c901875] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
2018-06-17T15:43:28.470347+00:00 app[web.1]: [ab5da2ad-516f-4b5f-864f-a9040c901875] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/puma-3.11.4/lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in `call'
2018-06-17T15:43:28.470348+00:00 app[web.1]: [ab5da2ad-516f-4b5f-864f-a9040c901875] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/puma-3.11.4/lib/puma/server.rb:632:in `handle_request'
2018-06-17T15:43:28.470350+00:00 app[web.1]: [ab5da2ad-516f-4b5f-864f-a9040c901875] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/puma-3.11.4/lib/puma/server.rb:446:in `process_client'
2018-06-17T15:43:28.470352+00:00 app[web.1]: [ab5da2ad-516f-4b5f-864f-a9040c901875] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/puma-3.11.4/lib/puma/server.rb:306:in `block in run'
2018-06-17T15:43:28.470354+00:00 app[web.1]: [ab5da2ad-516f-4b5f-864f-a9040c901875] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/puma-3.11.4/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `block in spawn_thread'
2018-06-17T15:43:28.290973+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/jobs" host=stark-fortress-73015.herokuapp.com request_id=100078cd-e2ed-4e6c-a0c9-9431a5073b8a fwd="176.115.15.103" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=10ms status=404 bytes=1902 protocol=https
2018-06-17T15:43:28.472955+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/uploads/post/image/1/las.jpg" host=stark-fortress-73015.herokuapp.com request_id=ab5da2ad-516f-4b5f-864f-a9040c901875 fwd="176.115.15.103" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=404 bytes=1902 protocol=https
2018-06-17T15:43:30.396198+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/jobs" host=stark-fortress-73015.herokuapp.com request_id=2faa34c7-c5a9-4698-8545-f35d6da49fd6 fwd="176.115.15.103" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=8ms status=404 bytes=1902 protocol=https
2018-06-17T15:43:30.388071+00:00 app[web.1]: [2faa34c7-c5a9-4698-8545-f35d6da49fd6] Started GET "/jobs" for 176.115.15.103 at 2018-06-17 15:43:30 +0000
2018-06-17T15:43:30.389225+00:00 app[web.1]: [2faa34c7-c5a9-4698-8545-f35d6da49fd6] Processing by JobsController#index as HTML
2018-06-17T15:43:30.392500+00:00 app[web.1]: [2faa34c7-c5a9-4698-8545-f35d6da49fd6]   Job Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  "jobs".* FROM "jobs" WHERE "jobs"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", nil], ["LIMIT", 1]]
2018-06-17T15:43:30.393049+00:00 app[web.1]: [2faa34c7-c5a9-4698-8545-f35d6da49fd6] Completed 404 Not Found in 4ms (ActiveRecord: 1.1ms)
2018-06-17T15:43:30.393666+00:00 app[web.1]: [2faa34c7-c5a9-4698-8545-f35d6da49fd6]
2018-06-17T15:43:30.393672+00:00 app[web.1]: [2faa34c7-c5a9-4698-8545-f35d6da49fd6] ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Job with 'id'=):
2018-06-17T15:43:30.393690+00:00 app[web.1]: [2faa34c7-c5a9-4698-8545-f35d6da49fd6]
2018-06-17T15:43:30.393716+00:00 app[web.1]: [2faa34c7-c5a9-4698-8545-f35d6da49fd6] app/controllers/jobs_controller.rb:6:in `set_job'
2018-06-17T15:43:39.857562+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/posts/2" host=stark-fortress-73015.herokuapp.com request_id=a27d3031-42b0-438d-bf76-83b18c7c7680 fwd="184.173.90.200" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=9ms status=404 bytes=1902 protocol=https
2018-06-17T15:43:39.850382+00:00 app[web.1]: [a27d3031-42b0-438d-bf76-83b18c7c7680] Started GET "/posts/2" for 184.173.90.200 at 2018-06-17 15:43:39 +0000
2018-06-17T15:43:39.851426+00:00 app[web.1]: [a27d3031-42b0-438d-bf76-83b18c7c7680] Processing by PostsController#show as HTML
2018-06-17T15:43:39.851505+00:00 app[web.1]: [a27d3031-42b0-438d-bf76-83b18c7c7680]   Parameters: {"id"=>"2"}
2018-06-17T15:43:39.855042+00:00 app[web.1]: [a27d3031-42b0-438d-bf76-83b18c7c7680]   Post Load (1.3ms)  SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
2018-06-17T15:43:39.855655+00:00 app[web.1]: [a27d3031-42b0-438d-bf76-83b18c7c7680] Completed 404 Not Found in 4ms (ActiveRecord: 1.3ms)
2018-06-17T15:43:39.856508+00:00 app[web.1]: [a27d3031-42b0-438d-bf76-83b18c7c7680]
2018-06-17T15:43:39.856551+00:00 app[web.1]: [a27d3031-42b0-438d-bf76-83b18c7c7680] ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Post with 'id'=2):
2018-06-17T15:43:39.856590+00:00 app[web.1]: [a27d3031-42b0-438d-bf76-83b18c7c7680]
2018-06-17T15:43:39.856638+00:00 app[web.1]: [a27d3031-42b0-438d-bf76-83b18c7c7680] app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:37:in `find_post'
2018-06-17T15:44:53.973056+00:00 heroku[run.7246]: Client connection closed. Sending SIGHUP to all processes
2018-06-17T15:44:59.003525+00:00 heroku[run.7246]: Client connection closed. Sending SIGHUP to all processes
```

Answer (score 1):

You have the error in you logs:

```
Started GET "/jobs" for 176.115.15.103 at 2018-06-17 15:43:30 +0000
Processing by JobsController#index as HTML
  Job Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  "jobs".* FROM "jobs" WHERE "jobs"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", nil], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Completed 404 Not Found in 4ms (ActiveRecord: 1.1ms)
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Job with 'id'=):
app/controllers/jobs_controller.rb:6:in `set_job'
```

Remove the index action of your `before_action :set_job` because it tries to reach a job from a param "id" which does not exist in the request (third line in the pasted code above)